# Что такое поиск с барьером? Как его реализовать? В чём его смысл?

Tags: c, массивы, алгоритм

Понимаю, что мы добавляем дополнительный элемент в массив (барьер), и больше не приходится задумываться над границами массива. Вот только одно не ясно: то число, которое мы ищем, мы сами вводим и заменяем предпоследний элемент — как это можно назвать поиском? Мы же уже знаем, где он находится. И можете написать полный вариант работоспособной программы с реализацией этого барьерного поиска?

Comment: Вот есть [хорошее видео There's Treasure Everywhere - Andrei Alexandrescu](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fd1_Miy1Clg). Там поиск с барьером как раз первая разбираемая тема.

Comment: [Sentinel value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value) - в Wikipedia достаточно хорошо объяснено (жаль нет перевода на русский).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Суть подобного поиска в том, что мы избавляемся от одного условия - проверки границ. Если взять линейный поиск в массиве чисел, то таким образом получим прирост производительности. Сравним два варианта:

```
//1
size_t find(int const *arr, size_t size, int value) {
   for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {//Первое условие в цикле
      if (arr[i] == value) {//Второе для проверки самого значения
         return i;
      }
   }
   return std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max();
}


//2
size_t find(int *arr, size_t size, int value) {
   if (size != 0) {
      int last = arr[size - 1];//Сохраним прежний элемент массива
      arr[size - 1] = value;//Гарантируем, что value есть в массиве
      //Есть гарантия того, что элемент есть в массиве, значит индекс можно не проверять
      size_t i = 0;
      for (i = 0; arr[i] != value; ++i) {//Одно условие в цикле
      }
      arr[size - 1] = last;//Восстанавливаем последний элемент
      if (i != (size - 1) || value == last) {//Не уткнулись в барьер или последний элемент был искомым
         return i;
      }
   }
   return std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max();
}
```

Когда-то я делал замеры подобной реализации. Т.к. мы избавились от одного условия, то цикл выполняется примерно в два раза быстрее. В начале и в конце у нас имеются дополнительные действия, но они производятся один раз, а не на каждой итерации цикла. Также реализация сделана так, что не требуется дополнительный элемент, но при этом приходится отказываться от константности. Надеюсь, что я правильно понял суть вопроса.

Comment: опечатка: `const int *`, а не  `int const *`... второе — константный указатель...

Comment: @Fat-Zer Вы ошибаетесь, записи ```int const *``` и ```const int *``` эквивалентны и это будут указатели на константы. А константный указатель - это ```int * const```. Особое внимание на положение const и "звездочки".

Comment: да, прошу прощения... моя не прав... видать, новый год всё ещё не кончился...

Comment: @Fat-Zer новый год только начался!

Comment: Я бы проверял, не является ли искомый  последним, сразу же :)

Comment: @Harry если нужно найти последнее вхождение, то да, а если первое, то нет.

Comment: Обычно ищется любое - просто, есть ли такой элемент (см. тот же `binary_search`, который просто `bool`)... но даже если надо первое - то по крайней мере не надо перезаписывать :)

Comment: @Harry всё зависит от цели. Когда-то нужно найти именно позицию (например, для дальнейшего удаления), когда-то просто проверить факт наличия. Ну а помимо binary_search, который проверяет факт наличия, есть еще lower_bound/upper_bound/equal_range, которые подходящие итераторы возвращают. Так что всё определяется задачей.

Answer (score 7):

Померил производительность кода @Croessmah'а на железе. В результате:

- Для массивов порядка L1 прирост скорости около 97%±5%
- Для массивов порядка L2

  - `uint64_t` даёт ~85% прироста
  - `uint32_t` даёт по-прежнему ~95% прироста
- Для массивов умещающихся в L3:

  - `uint64_t` — 70%
  - `uint32_t` — 91~97%
- Для массивов значительно превосходящих L3:

  - `uint64_t` — барьерный поиск даёт всего 10% прироста
  - `uint32_t` — даёт 50% прироста.

Код /прошу извинить за смесь плюсов и Си/

Cобирался `x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-g++-6.4.0 -O3 -fno-inline -march=native` железо: Core i5-3570K):

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <limits>

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define NUM_TRIES 128
#define SECTION_SZ 8
#define MIN_COUNTABLE_TIME ( 50 * 1000.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC)

template <typename T>
ssize_t find(T const *arr, size_t size, T value) {
   for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {//Первое условие в цикле
      if (arr[i] == value) {//Второе для проверки самого значения
         return i;
      }
   }
   return -1;
}

template <typename T>
ssize_t barier(T *arr, size_t size, T value) {
   if (size != 0) {
      T last = arr[size - 1];//Сохраним прежний элемент массива
      arr[size - 1] = value;//Гарантируем, что value есть в массиве
      //Есть гарантия того, что элемент есть в массиве, значит индекс можно не проверять
      size_t i = 0;
      for (i = 0; arr[i] != value; ++i) {//Одно условие в цикле
      }
      arr[size - 1] = last;//Восстанавливаем последний элемент
      if (i != (size - 1) || value == last) {//Не уткнулись в барьер или последний элемент был искомым
         return i;
      }
   }
   return -1;
}

template <typename T>
void mesure_time (size_t num) {
    T *arr = static_cast<T*> (malloc (num * sizeof(T)));
    assert (arr);

    if (std::numeric_limits<T>::max() > num) {
        for (size_t i=0; i<num; i++) {
            arr[i] = i;
        }
    } else {
        for (size_t i=0; i<num; i++) {
            arr[i] = i*(std::numeric_limits<T>::max() - 1) / num;
        }
    }


    printf("number of elements = %ld\n", num);
    printf("sizeof(T)          = %zd\n", sizeof(T));

    if (num*sizeof(T) < 16L*1024L*1024L) {
        printf("size of array      = %zdk\n", sizeof(T) * num / 1024);
    } else {
        printf("size of array      = %zdM\n", sizeof(T) * num / 1024 / 1024);
    }

    printf ("         N |   find(ms) | barier(ms) |         diff | surplus\n");

    double total_avg_find = 0;
    double total_avg_barier = 0;
    int valid = 0;

    T search_key = std::numeric_limits<T>::max();
    for (size_t i=num; i>32; i/=2, search_key = arr[i]) {
        double avg_find;
        double avg_barier;

        clock_t start_time = clock();
        ssize_t found_find = find (arr, num, search_key);
        double wt_find = (clock() - start_time) * (1000. / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

        start_time = clock();
        ssize_t found_barier =  barier(arr, num, search_key);
        double wt_barier = (clock() - start_time) * (1000. / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

        assert (found_find == found_barier);

        if ( wt_find > MIN_COUNTABLE_TIME && wt_barier > MIN_COUNTABLE_TIME ) {
            // get a per-iteration count
            for (int j = 1; j<NUM_TRIES; j++) {
                start_time = clock();
                found_barier =  barier(arr, num, search_key);
                wt_barier += (clock() - start_time) * (1000. / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

                start_time = clock();
                found_find =  find(arr, num, search_key);
                wt_find += (clock() - start_time) * (1000. / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

                assert (found_find == found_barier);
            }

        } else {
            wt_find = 0;
            wt_barier = 0;
            ssize_t found_find[NUM_TRIES];
            ssize_t found_barier[NUM_TRIES];
            bool to_small_failure = false;

            for (int j = 1; j<NUM_TRIES; j++) {
                // get overall count
                start_time = clock();
                for (int k = 0; k<NUM_TRIES; k++) {
                    found_find[k] =  find(arr, num, search_key);
                }
                wt_find += (clock() - start_time) * (1000. / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

                start_time = clock();
                for (int k = 0; k<NUM_TRIES; k++) {
                    found_barier[k] =  barier(arr, num, search_key);
                }
                wt_barier += (clock() - start_time) * (1000. / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

                for (int k = 0; k<NUM_TRIES; k++) {
                    assert(found_find[k] == found_barier[k]);
                }

                if ( wt_find < MIN_COUNTABLE_TIME || wt_barier < MIN_COUNTABLE_TIME ) {
                    to_small_failure = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (to_small_failure) {
                // invalid; some results, are too small to mesure
                continue;
            }
            wt_find /= NUM_TRIES;
            wt_barier /= NUM_TRIES;
        }
        valid ++;

        avg_find = wt_find / NUM_TRIES;
        avg_barier = wt_barier / NUM_TRIES;

        double diff = avg_find - avg_barier;
        double surplus = diff * 100 / avg_barier;

        printf ("%10zd | %8.3lgms | %8.3lgms | %10.3lgms | %+7.2lf%%\n",
                found_find, avg_find,  avg_barier, diff, surplus);
        total_avg_find   += avg_find;
        total_avg_barier += avg_barier;
    }
    total_avg_find   /= valid;
    total_avg_barier /= valid;

    double diff = total_avg_find - total_avg_barier;
    double surplus = diff * 100 / total_avg_barier;

    printf ("\n");
    printf ("Avg time:    %8.3lgms | %8.3lgms | %10.3lgms | %+7.2lf%%\n",
            total_avg_find, total_avg_barier, diff, surplus);

    free (arr);
}

int main() {
    // L1-fit array (32K-4K)
    mesure_time<uint8_t>  ( 1024L*28 );
    printf ("--------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    mesure_time<uint32_t> ( 1024L*28 / 4 );
    printf ("--------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    mesure_time<uint64_t> ( 1024L*28 / 8 );
    printf ("==============================================================\n");

    // L2-fit array (256K-8K)
    mesure_time<uint32_t> ( 1024L*248 / 4 );
    printf ("--------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    mesure_time<uint64_t> ( 1024L*248 / 8 );
    printf ("==============================================================\n");

    // L2-excess array 1M
    mesure_time<uint32_t> ( 1024L*1024L / 4 );
    printf ("--------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    mesure_time<uint64_t> ( 1024L*1024L / 8 );
    printf ("==============================================================\n");

    // L3-fit array 6M-32K
    mesure_time<uint32_t> ( (1024L*1024L*6 - 1024L*32) / 4);
    printf ("==============================================================\n");
    mesure_time<uint64_t> ( (1024L*1024L*6 - 1024L*32) / 8);
    printf ("==============================================================\n");

    // L3-excess array (16M)
    mesure_time<uint8_t>  ( 1024L*1024L*16 );
    printf ("--------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    mesure_time<uint32_t> ( 1024L*1024L*16 / 4);
    printf ("--------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    mesure_time<uint64_t> ( 1024L*1024L*16 / 8);
    printf ("==============================================================\n");

    // huge array (512M)
    mesure_time<uint32_t> ( 1024L*1024L*512 / 4);
    printf ("--------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    mesure_time<uint64_t> ( 1024L*1024L*512 / 8);
    printf ("==============================================================\n");

    return 0;
}
```

---

Результаты:

```
number of elements = 28672
sizeof(T)          = 1
size of array      = 28k
         N |   find(ms) | barier(ms) |         diff | surplus
        -1 |   0.0153ms |  0.00764ms |    0.00771ms | +101.00%
     14336 |  0.00757ms |  0.00379ms |    0.00377ms |  +99.47%
      7112 |  0.00375ms |   0.0019ms |    0.00185ms |  +97.52%
      3500 |  0.00186ms | 0.000948ms |   0.000909ms |  +95.91%
      1694 | 0.000901ms | 0.000464ms |   0.000438ms |  +94.37%

Avg time:     0.00588ms |  0.00295ms |    0.00294ms |  +99.62%
--------------------------------------------------------------
number of elements = 7168
sizeof(T)          = 4
size of array      = 28k
         N |   find(ms) | barier(ms) |         diff | surplus
        -1 |  0.00378ms |   0.0019ms |    0.00188ms |  +98.55%
      3584 |   0.0019ms | 0.000964ms |   0.000934ms |  +96.90%
      1792 | 0.000952ms | 0.000491ms |   0.000461ms |  +93.85%

Avg time:     0.00221ms |  0.00112ms |    0.00109ms |  +97.39%
--------------------------------------------------------------
number of elements = 3584
sizeof(T)          = 8
size of array      = 28k
         N |   find(ms) | barier(ms) |         diff | surplus
        -1 |   0.0019ms | 0.000966ms |   0.000935ms |  +96.72%
      1792 | 0.000956ms |  0.00049ms |   0.000466ms |  +95.24%

Avg time:     0.00143ms | 0.000728ms |   0.000701ms |  +96.22%
==============================================================
number of elements = 63488
sizeof(T)          = 4
size of array      = 248k
         N |   find(ms) | barier(ms) |         diff | surplus
        -1 |   0.0334ms |   0.0168ms |     0.0166ms |  +98.47%
     31744 |   0.0168ms |  0.00843ms |    0.00837ms |  +99.36%
     15872 |  0.00839ms |  0.00421ms |    0.00417ms |  +99.05%
      7936 |   0.0042ms |  0.00212ms |    0.00207ms |  +97.66%
      3968 |   0.0021ms |  0.00106ms |    0.00104ms |  +97.36%
      1984 |  0.00105ms | 0.000542ms |   0.000509ms |  +94.02%

Avg time:       0.011ms |  0.00554ms |    0.00546ms |  +98.61%
--------------------------------------------------------------
number of elements = 31744
sizeof(T)          = 8
size of array      = 248k
         N |   find(ms) | barier(ms) |         diff | surplus
        -1 |   0.0168ms |  0.00948ms |    0.00734ms |  +77.50%
     15872 |  0.00845ms |  0.00459ms |    0.00386ms |  +84.07%
      7936 |  0.00419ms |  0.00227ms |    0.00192ms |  +84.65%
      3968 |  0.00213ms |  0.00108ms |    0.00104ms |  +96.40%
      1984 |  0.00106ms | 0.000541ms |   0.000516ms |  +95.34%

Avg time:     0.00653ms |  0.00359ms |    0.00294ms |  +81.76%
==============================================================
number of elements = 262144
sizeof(T)          = 4
size of array      = 1024k
         N |   find(ms) | barier(ms) |         diff | surplus
        -1 |    0.141ms |   0.0714ms |     0.0694ms |  +97.16%
    131072 |   0.0692ms |   0.0352ms |      0.034ms |  +96.72%
     65536 |   0.0347ms |   0.0174ms |     0.0173ms |  +99.14%
     32768 |   0.0173ms |  0.00869ms |    0.00857ms |  +98.56%
     16384 |  0.00863ms |  0.00433ms |     0.0043ms |  +99.24%
      8192 |  0.00432ms |  0.00219ms |    0.00213ms |  +97.00%
      4096 |  0.00216ms |   0.0011ms |    0.00107ms |  +97.57%
      2048 |  0.00108ms | 0.000556ms |   0.000529ms |  +95.03%

Avg time:      0.0348ms |   0.0176ms |     0.0172ms |  +97.44%
--------------------------------------------------------------
number of elements = 131072
sizeof(T)          = 8
size of array      = 1024k
         N |   find(ms) | barier(ms) |         diff | surplus
        -1 |   0.0692ms |   0.0405ms |     0.0286ms |  +70.56%
     65536 |   0.0346ms |   0.0203ms |     0.0143ms |  +70.65%
     32768 |   0.0173ms |  0.00976ms |    0.00753ms |  +77.19%
     16384 |  0.00865ms |  0.00469ms |    0.00396ms |  +84.49%
      8192 |  0.00437ms |  0.00235ms |    0.00202ms |  +85.73%
      4096 |  0.00218ms |  0.00111ms |    0.00107ms |  +96.06%
      2048 |  0.00108ms | 0.000558ms |   0.000527ms |  +94.55%

Avg time:      0.0196ms |   0.0113ms |    0.00829ms |  +73.20%
==============================================================
number of elements = 1564672
sizeof(T)          = 4
size of array      = 6112k
         N |   find(ms) | barier(ms) |         diff | surplus
        -1 |    0.855ms |    0.506ms |      0.348ms |  +68.82%
    782336 |    0.418ms |    0.219ms |      0.199ms |  +91.23%
    391168 |     0.21ms |    0.107ms |      0.103ms |  +96.36%
    195584 |    0.105ms |   0.0534ms |     0.0515ms |  +96.50%
     97792 |   0.0516ms |   0.0263ms |     0.0254ms |  +96.50%
     48896 |   0.0259ms |    0.013ms |     0.0129ms |  +99.62%
     24448 |   0.0129ms |  0.00645ms |    0.00642ms |  +99.53%
     12224 |   0.0065ms |  0.00326ms |    0.00324ms |  +99.25%
      6112 |  0.00323ms |  0.00163ms |     0.0016ms |  +98.46%
      3056 |  0.00163ms | 0.000827ms |   0.000802ms |  +96.96%
      1528 | 0.000825ms | 0.000429ms |   0.000396ms |  +92.40%

Avg time:       0.154ms |   0.0852ms |     0.0685ms |  +80.37%
==============================================================
number of elements = 782336
sizeof(T)          = 8
size of array      = 6112k
         N |   find(ms) | barier(ms) |         diff | surplus
        -1 |    0.456ms |    0.339ms |      0.118ms |  +34.71%
    391168 |    0.212ms |    0.132ms |     0.0806ms |  +61.26%
    195584 |    0.105ms |   0.0621ms |     0.0433ms |  +69.73%
     97792 |   0.0518ms |   0.0303ms |     0.0215ms |  +70.92%
     48896 |   0.0259ms |   0.0151ms |     0.0108ms |  +71.66%
     24448 |    0.013ms |  0.00728ms |     0.0057ms |  +78.25%
     12224 |   0.0065ms |  0.00353ms |    0.00297ms |  +84.06%
      6112 |  0.00327ms |  0.00177ms |     0.0015ms |  +84.76%
      3056 |  0.00163ms | 0.000828ms |   0.000801ms |  +96.71%
      1528 | 0.000813ms | 0.000422ms |   0.000391ms |  +92.61%

Avg time:      0.0877ms |   0.0591ms |     0.0285ms |  +48.20%
==============================================================
number of elements = 16777216
sizeof(T)          = 1
size of array      = 16M
         N |   find(ms) | barier(ms) |         diff | surplus
        -1 |     9.17ms |     4.91ms |       4.26ms |  +86.67%
   8388608 |     4.52ms |     2.42ms |        2.1ms |  +87.04%
   4161278 |     2.23ms |     1.15ms |       1.09ms |  +94.93%
   2047613 |     1.13ms |    0.571ms |      0.561ms |  +98.29%
    990781 |    0.545ms |    0.273ms |      0.271ms |  +99.25%
    462365 |    0.249ms |    0.126ms |      0.123ms |  +98.20%
    198157 |    0.107ms |   0.0537ms |      0.053ms |  +98.62%
     66053 |    0.036ms |   0.0181ms |     0.0179ms |  +98.98%

Avg time:        2.25ms |     1.19ms |       1.06ms |  +89.06%
--------------------------------------------------------------
number of elements = 4194304
sizeof(T)          = 4
size of array      = 16M
         N |   find(ms) | barier(ms) |         diff | surplus
        -1 |     2.32ms |     1.52ms |      0.802ms |  +52.91%
   2097152 |     1.15ms |    0.717ms |      0.436ms |  +60.85%
   1048576 |    0.581ms |    0.323ms |      0.258ms |  +80.11%
    524288 |    0.285ms |    0.147ms |      0.138ms |  +94.08%
    262144 |    0.144ms |   0.0732ms |     0.0703ms |  +96.06%
    131072 |   0.0708ms |    0.036ms |     0.0348ms |  +96.56%
     65536 |   0.0352ms |   0.0177ms |     0.0175ms |  +98.37%
     32768 |   0.0181ms |  0.00907ms |    0.00899ms |  +99.15%
     16384 |  0.00899ms |  0.00453ms |    0.00446ms |  +98.59%
      8192 |   0.0045ms |  0.00228ms |    0.00222ms |  +97.50%
      4096 |  0.00228ms |  0.00115ms |    0.00113ms |  +98.49%
      2048 |  0.00114ms | 0.000582ms |   0.000558ms |  +95.79%

Avg time:       0.385ms |    0.237ms |      0.148ms |  +62.34%
--------------------------------------------------------------
number of elements = 2097152
sizeof(T)          = 8
size of array      = 16M
         N |   find(ms) | barier(ms) |         diff | surplus
        -1 |     1.28ms |     1.15ms |      0.133ms |  +11.62%
   1048576 |    0.619ms |    0.497ms |      0.122ms |  +24.52%
    524288 |     0.29ms |     0.19ms |     0.0999ms |  +52.51%
    262144 |    0.141ms |   0.0836ms |     0.0572ms |  +68.35%
    131072 |   0.0712ms |   0.0417ms |     0.0295ms |  +70.80%
     65536 |   0.0348ms |   0.0204ms |     0.0144ms |  +70.36%
     32768 |   0.0173ms |  0.00983ms |     0.0075ms |  +76.28%
     16384 |  0.00877ms |  0.00477ms |      0.004ms |  +83.77%
      8192 |   0.0044ms |  0.00238ms |    0.00201ms |  +84.40%
      4096 |   0.0022ms |  0.00112ms |    0.00107ms |  +95.35%
      2048 |  0.00115ms |  0.00059ms |   0.000555ms |  +94.06%

Avg time:       0.224ms |    0.182ms |     0.0428ms |  +23.59%
==============================================================
number of elements = 134217728
sizeof(T)          = 4
size of array      = 512M
         N |   find(ms) | barier(ms) |         diff | surplus
        -1 |     72.9ms |     48.1ms |       24.8ms |  +51.61%
  67108864 |     36.6ms |     24.2ms |       12.4ms |  +51.43%
  33554432 |     18.2ms |     12.1ms |       6.14ms |  +50.88%
  16777216 |     9.06ms |     5.98ms |       3.08ms |  +51.45%
   8388608 |     4.53ms |     2.98ms |       1.55ms |  +52.18%
   4194304 |     2.27ms |     1.46ms |      0.809ms |  +55.45%
   2097152 |     1.14ms |    0.704ms |      0.436ms |  +61.95%
   1048576 |    0.562ms |    0.305ms |      0.257ms |  +84.43%
    524288 |    0.278ms |    0.142ms |      0.136ms |  +95.28%
    262144 |    0.139ms |   0.0707ms |     0.0688ms |  +97.28%
    131072 |   0.0704ms |   0.0359ms |     0.0345ms |  +96.25%
     65536 |    0.035ms |   0.0176ms |     0.0173ms |  +98.45%
     32768 |    0.018ms |  0.00904ms |    0.00896ms |  +99.17%
     16384 |  0.00883ms |  0.00444ms |    0.00438ms |  +98.64%
      8192 |  0.00432ms |  0.00219ms |    0.00214ms |  +97.83%
      4096 |  0.00226ms |  0.00114ms |    0.00112ms |  +97.77%
      2048 |  0.00113ms |  0.00058ms |    0.00055ms |  +94.82%

Avg time:        8.58ms |     5.65ms |       2.93ms |  +51.85%
--------------------------------------------------------------
number of elements = 67108864
sizeof(T)          = 8
size of array      = 512M
         N |   find(ms) | barier(ms) |         diff | surplus
        -1 |     39.6ms |     35.1ms |       4.48ms |  +12.76%
  33554432 |       20ms |     17.9ms |       2.08ms |  +11.64%
  16777216 |     9.93ms |     8.89ms |       1.04ms |  +11.66%
   8388608 |     4.98ms |     4.47ms |       0.51ms |  +11.40%
   4194304 |     2.51ms |     2.27ms |      0.235ms |  +10.35%
   2097152 |     1.24ms |     1.14ms |      0.105ms |   +9.24%
   1048576 |    0.612ms |    0.488ms |      0.124ms |  +25.41%
    524288 |    0.296ms |    0.202ms |      0.094ms |  +46.55%
    262144 |    0.146ms |   0.0872ms |     0.0587ms |  +67.31%
    131072 |   0.0703ms |   0.0412ms |     0.0292ms |  +70.92%
     65536 |   0.0355ms |   0.0207ms |     0.0147ms |  +71.01%
     32768 |   0.0176ms |  0.00964ms |      0.008ms |  +83.06%
     16384 |  0.00903ms |  0.00486ms |    0.00416ms |  +85.62%
      8192 |   0.0045ms |  0.00244ms |    0.00206ms |  +84.45%
      4096 |  0.00226ms |  0.00115ms |    0.00111ms |  +96.03%
      2048 |  0.00114ms | 0.000594ms |    0.00055ms |  +92.70%

Avg time:        4.96ms |     4.42ms |      0.549ms |  +12.44%
==============================================================
```

- `N` — индекс найденного элемента
- `find(ms)` — среднее время за `NUM_TRIES` проходов в миллисекундах поиска оного с помощью `find()`
- `barier(ms)` — аналогично, с помощью барьерного поиска.
- `diff` — разница двух предыдущих.
- `surplus` — прирост производительности в процентах, отношение diff к barier.

Comment: Серьезный подход. А у вас реально было, что после `continue` по `to_small_failure = true` какие-то из следующих замеров (с тем же массивом)  попадали в результат?

Comment: @avp, нет. Вполне можно заменить на `break` в конечном варианте. Изначально цикл был в прямом порядке, с увеличением `i` но во-первых показалось, что результаты смазывались на границе размеров кеша, а во-вторых обратный вывод кажется более наглядным... поэтому развернул цикл, а `continue` остался... вообще говоря, тесты здесь сильно избыточны. Последние два теста фактически позволяют сделать все выводы.