# нужен алгоритм быстрого последовательного поиска в массиве

Tags: c++

Понял как делать бинарный и последовательный поиск но не могу найти алгоритм для быстрого последовательно

Comment: Последовательный быстрым не бывает :) - просто перебираете все по порядку. Вам [этого](https://www.google.com/search?ei=65NhX52hOoeZkwW487vADA&q=%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9+%D0%B8+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA+C%2B%2B) мало?

Comment: В `С++` полно вариантов в стандартной либе, см https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm

Comment: Может это подойдет: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/765910/189960

Answer (score 3):

Потому что его нет. Если данные в массиве никак не упорядочены, придется перебирать подряд весь массив.
Из ускорений тут можно придумать разве что параллельные обработки и фильтр Блума.
Первые позволяют ускорится кратно числу задействованных ядер (при условии, что все данные помещаются в память), второй позволяет понять, то данных в массиве точно нет и поиск затевать не стоит.